# Is there a difference between floor and truncate in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does there exist a difference in functionality between `floor` and `truncate` in Haskell?

They seem to perform the same functionality and they have the same type signature:

- `truncate :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`
- `floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`

Comment: Total Haskell newbie, but as in most other languages, you'll likely see a difference with negative numbers…

Comment: This was indeed my problem. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, for negative numbers. If we read the documentation, we see:

> **`truncate :: Integral b => a -> b`**
>
> `truncate x` returns the integer nearest `x` between zero and `x`

and:

> **`floor :: Integral b => a -> b`**
>
> `floor x` returns the greatest integer not greater than `x`

So if we enter a **negative number**, like `-3.5` we obtain:

```
Prelude> truncate (-3.5)
-3
Prelude> floor (-3.5)
-4
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and the reference to the docs. I was indeed only verifying it with positive numbers.

Answer (score 7):

It's not haskell specific, but there's a difference between those functions. Floor means the highest integer no higher than a given number. Truncate means to remove at some length, in this case the fractional part. Those have the same effect for zero and positive numbers, but not negative.

Here's a quick comparison in Python:

```
>>> for i in range(-5,6):
...   j=0.5*i
...   print(j,floor(j),ceil(j),trunc(j),round(j))
...
-2.5 -3 -2 -2 -2
-2.0 -2 -2 -2 -2
-1.5 -2 -1 -1 -2
-1.0 -1 -1 -1 -1
-0.5 -1 0 0 0
0.0 0 0 0 0
0.5 0 1 0 0
1.0 1 1 1 1
1.5 1 2 1 2
2.0 2 2 2 2
2.5 2 3 2 2
```

Essentially trunc() goes towards zero and floor() towards negative infinity.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the source code the difference emerges quite quickly:

```
truncate x          =  m  where (m,_) = properFraction x
```

and

```
floor x             =  if r < 0 then n - 1 else n
                       where (n,r) = properFraction x
```

we see the difference will only emerge on negative numbers and so:

```
Prelude> floor (negate 2.1)
-3
Prelude> truncate (negate 2.1)
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Truncate:

```
1    -->  1 
3.1  -->  3
3.9  -->  3
-2.1 --> -2
-2.9 --> -2
```

Floor:

```
1    -->  1 
3.1  -->  3
3.9  -->  3
-2.1 --> -2
-2.9 --> -3 (Different!...)
```

Comment: Mind that `floor (-2.1)` is `-3`.